# Killing setInterval upon object deletion

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<script>
   var global = {};
   global.obj = {
      // when called this function will cause 'hello' to be output to the
      // console every 1 second
      repeat: function () {
         setInterval(function () {
            console.log('hello');
         }, 1000);
      }
   }

   global.obj.repeat();
   global.obj = [];

   // even after we overwrite global.obj, 'hello' 
   // continues to be output to the console every second
</script>
</html>
```

I want to write a function similar to repeat, except when global.obj is overwritten, setInterval will stop being called

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use getters/setters, [Mozilla has some good docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) on this.

You may have to tweak it a bit:

```
var intervalRef = null;

var global = {objRef: {}};
global.__defineSetter__("obj", function(o) {
  if (intervalRef)
    clearInterval(intervalRef);
  intervalRef = null;
  global.objRef = o;
});

global.__defineGetter__("obj", function() {
  return global.objRef;
});

global.obj = {
  repeat: function () {
     intervalRef = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('hello');
     }, 1000);
  }
}

global.obj.repeat();
setTimeout(function() { //this just demonstrates that you can let it run for 5 secs before clearing the timer.
  global.obj = [];
}, 5000);
```

I tested this and verified that it works.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rcTjH/1/) Fiddle:

```
// html
<p id="stopper">Click</p>​

// js
var counter = new Object();

counter.timer = setInterval( function(){
    console.log("Hello!");
}, 1000 );

$("#stopper").click(function(){
    console.log("Stopping");
    clearInterval(counter.timer);
});
​
```